# What does the acronym CMC refer to in this context?

Tags: cooling, water-cooling, hpc, rack

I am doing a research project on SGI High Performance Computers, specifically the SGI ICE XA platform. In the datasheet (found [here](https://www.sgi.com/pdfs/4529.pdf)), I came across [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkImz.png).

I am wondering what the acronym CMC means in this context. I have researched the acronym some, and found that it most commonly means "Computer-mediated communication". However, I'm not really sure how that would really apply in this situation, as Computer-mediated communication seems to refer to a process involving a human. The only option I can imagine if this definition applies is some sort of interface terminal for debugging or direction connections.

What does this acronym actually mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What does this acronym actually mean?

It stands for **C**hassis **M**anagement **C**ontroller

> **Chassis Management Controller**
>
> The chassis management controller (CMC) in the rear of the IRU, as
>   shown in Figure 1-5, and Figure 1-6, supports powering up and down of
>   the compute blades and environmental monitoring of all units within
>   the IRU. The CMC sends operational requests to the baseboard manager
>   controller (BMC) on each compute node. The CMC provides data collected
>   from the compute nodes within the IRU to the system management node
>   upon request. The CMC blade on the right side of the IRU is the
>   primary CMC. A secondary CMC is currently not supported.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Source [Chapter 1. Introducing Altix UV System Control Topology](http://www.nacad.ufrj.br/online/sgi/admin/007-5636-005/sgi_html/ch01.html#id5177451)